# Android Activity flickers on some devices

Tags: android, scrollview

I have created a simple Android activity and added some cardviews and imageviews for the profile pictures.

The images are inside a scrollview. On a few devices, the scrollview scrolls automatically. I cannot reproduce the reason. After clearing the cache in the app settings, the problem was solved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_shadow">
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/profileIMG"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp">


        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/userProfileImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
             />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/backToMenu"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"

        android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:tint="#fff"
        android:contentDescription="Benutzer auswählen"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_white_24" />
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:padding="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

    android:background="@drawable/title"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:text="Wählen Sie das zu beobachtende Kind aus"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
<!-- android:layout_below="@id/title"-->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/childTable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:stretchColumns="*">

        <TableRow/>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_items"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_items"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_childselection" />
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I did find some redundancies on your XML layout that might cause the flickering.

> Remove your `android:layout_weight="1`, its not generally used in
> `ScrollView`

> Try to modify your `ImageView` specifically as it may be the culprit
> behind flickering issue. Change your `layout_width` and
> `layout_height` into `wrap_content` or something specific.

Also try setting your `<ScrollView>` to `android:focusableInTouchMode="true">` to make sure views are automatically getting focus which could cause scrolling.

You can also try to disable scrolling programmatically and enable it when needed.

```
scrollView.setEnabled(false);
```

If none works it maybe some device specific issues.